# Why this.add is not a function in the object context

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

In the following example I don't clearly understand why `this.add` is not defined. I suspect that it is because the arrows function are executed immediately and at the moment of compilation and the `add` function does not yet exist. Is this assumption correct? Or I'm missing something.

```
const arr= [1, 2, 3]
const squares = {  
  num: (arr) => {
    return arr.map((x) => {
      return (x * x) + this.add()
    })
  },
  add: () => {
    return 1
  }
}
//TypeError: this.add is not a function
console.log(squares.num(arr))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `lexical this` all the way out of the object. You'll need to avoid using an arrow function for `num`:

See [documentation for arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> "An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this..."

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const squares = {
  num: function(arr) {
    return arr.map((x) => {
      return (x * x) + this.add()
    })
  },
  add: () => {
    return 1
  }
}
console.log(squares.num(arr))
```

Comment: The lexical scoping of “this” in the previous example means that is only available inside the arrow function `{ }`?

Comment: @James: It means that `this` inside the arrow function refers to whatever `this` refers to in the scope where `squares` and `arr` are defined... it works exactly like you would expect any other variable to work.

Comment: The following notes from the MDN documentation were key to understand: 

1). Arrow functions used as methods: As stated previously, arrow function expressions are best suited for non-method functions.

2). An arrow function does not create its own this, the this value of the enclosing execution context is used.

Comment: @James, I apologize for responding so late, I was needed away from my computer. I'm glad that you were able to get this figured and found other documentation that explained how it works.